# Show that $f(z)$ not differentiable at $z=0$ by letting $\Delta z \rightarrow $ first along the x-axis and then along the line $y=x$

Tags: complex-analysis

Show that $f(z)=\begin{cases}0 \text{ if } z=0\\
\frac{x^3-y^3}{x^2+y^2}+i\frac{x^3+y^3}{x^2+y^2} \text{ if } 0 \neq z 
\end{cases}$  is not differentiable at $z=0$ by letting $\Delta z \rightarrow 0 $ first along the x-axis and then along the line $y=x$.

First I have problem with formulating a definition of derivative in terms of $x,y,\Delta x, \Delta y$. I'm wondering if the following definition is correct $\lim_{(\Delta x,\Delta y)\rightarrow (0,0)}\frac{u(x+\Delta x,y+\Delta y)+iv(x+\Delta x, y+\Delta y)-u(x,y)-v(x,y)}{\Delta x +i\Delta y} $.

Further, if $\Delta z \rightarrow 0 $ along the x-axis then $\lim_ {(0,\Delta y)\rightarrow (0,0)}$ but what type of limit should it be if $\Delta z \rightarrow 0 $ along  $y=x$?

Comment: (1) You have a missing "$i$" in the second "$iv$" (2) The Definition is Correct , but you may not get that "$u,v$" format in all Cases , Eg $f(z)=z^2+3$ (3) You must use numerator $[f(z+\delta z) - f(z)]$ while calculating the Derivative. The Problem is asking you to show that this is not well Defined when $z$ is tending to $0$. (4) Actually it is telling you that when considering $z=x+i0$ & $z=0+iy$ , where both are tending to $z=0+i0$ , you will get inconsistent limits !

Answer (score 1):

First, in the definition of derivatives I would write $\Delta z$ everywhere in place of $\Delta x, \Delta y$. This is to emphasize that every direction on the complex plane that eventually vanishes at zero is included. Note well that complex derivatives are stronger than the associated two variable derivatives (when we represent the complex plane by the Euclidean 2d plane).

Second, if the perturbation vanishes on the x direction simply set z = x where x is real. Then send x to 0. Hence in your notation, you should write $\Delta x, 0$ vanishing to 0 instead. Along the direction y = x, you can simply set $z = x + ix$ for all x in real. Check that this defines the line y = x. You then send x to 0 and see what goes wrong.